# object is not in the database when django post_save is running?

Tags: django, database, signals

I'm not sure what this ticket is talking about is what i'm experiencing.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14051

MyClass.objects.create() calls post_save() handler, and inside one of the handler, I do `Myclass.objects.filter(id=instance.id)` and it returns nothing.

So when you are inside post_save signal handler, 
your instance is not yet found in the DB because it 's not committed yet?

Is this true?

---

this is `create` part

```
     thread = ReviewThread.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

each review_thread has a review_meta (foreign_key) and related_name is 'review_threads'

```
 class ReviewThread(forum_models.Thread):

     thread = models.OneToOneField(forum_models.Thread, parent_link=True)
     review_meta = models.ForeignKey(ReviewMeta, related_name='review_threads')
```

This is the receiving part

```
 def maybe_update_review_meta_primary_image(review_thread):

     ReviewThread.objects.filter(id=review_thread.id) #returns nothing
     #...

 @receiver(post_save, sender=ReviewThread)
 def update_review_meta(sender, instance, **kwargs):

     review_thread = instance

     maybe_update_review_meta_primary_image(review_thread)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple databases? (for example a primary and a read only slave) then this might happen if the slave is lagging behind

Comment: I 'll check on it...

Answer (score 0):

If you use transactions then yes, it is true.  And it is a pretty valid behaviour.

Comment: umm i'm not using anything beyond normal `save(), create()` call. I'm suprised to see that `MyClass.objects.filter(id=instance.id)` returns nothing inside post_save which is called because of `MyClass.objects.create()`

Comment: This is not the issue described at ticked you provided.  Celery task is run in another process/transaction.  If your code runs inside one transaction then all should work just fine.  Show your real code (model and signal), please.

Comment: I run your code inside `transaction.atomic()` and it works without any issues.   `print ReviewThread.objects.filter(id=review_thread.id)` prints the queryset with the one instance in it.

Comment: ok.. that's what I expected.. so I'm experiencing something that's not expected.. Thanks for testing.. I'm not sure why I'm seeing this then... :(

Comment: Check the `instance.id` attribute.  Does it have the valid value?

Comment: yes it does have a value. and I queried with it in separate django shell (shell_plus) and nothing returned either